# Drawing Tools - Get Coordinates: drag doesn't work

Tags: plotting, drawing

My *Mathematica* version is 10.3. When I drag with Get Coordinates function under the Drawing Tools it does not work. For example, I cannot mark a set of points along the path and cannot use alt-drag/opt-drag to mark a rectangular area. May anybody help me with this bug.

Comment: I second this comment.  It used to work in previous versions,  where you could drag and create a set of points,  and then copy and use them in a graphics object, etc.   I haven't had to use this feature for a while,  but I have noticed that it seems to be broken.  (unless the way to do it has changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same problem, found workaround (not ideal but works as a way to get a list of coordinates): use the freehand line tool from the Drawing Tools palette to draw a freehand line tracing over the path that you want the coordinates of. Then click on the freehand line that you drew, which will cause it to be selected (a rectangular box with sizing handles will appear around it). Right click and select "Copy Graphics Selection".

In a new cell, type (for example) `img =` and to the right of the equal sign, right click and select Paste. This will paste the drawing object into the cell as a graphic. When you execute the cell, the drawing object is assigned to the variable `img`, and you can now access the graphics primitives making up the object. So, for example, if you type `InputForm[img]` the output will include a `Line` object with a long list of coordinate pairs.